# how to find the address of data in memory?

Tags: c++, memory-address

i need to find a way how to find the address's for value of another program. i find the address before hand but i don't know how to find them again after i close and reopen the program with out searching for them again (i need the program to find them on it's own).
anyone know how i can do this (sorry if im unclear i don't know how to explain it really)
if your confused just ask and i'll try to make it clear

im using C++

Comment: Maybe if you posted some code for what you *expect* to work and isn't, it will be clearer.

Comment: This may be impossible, so you should explain **why** you're trying to do it, and maybe we'd be able to help.

Comment: :\ i can't post code because i don't have any real code. all of my code is for my old version that makes me find a address to work off so it would be point less to post it. :(

also im not really sure how to explain it that well because if i did i would have posted more. but the main point of what im trying to do right now is to find the address of a programs value with out ME searching for it each time. so like i can open my program and it will find all of the address's in that program that i need to know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your platform is Windows, I find it convenient to inject your own DLL into the target process. From there, you could possibly do a heap walk and look for the value. After you've got it, send it back to your process via IPC (for instance, with Boost's message_queue).

**EDIT**

*Blood*, as you requested, here's a little code and a food for thought. The DLL itself is pretty simple, for example something like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

/** You can use this one to examine the given memory blocks.
  * However, since you're inside another process, you cannot use
  * std::cout. But you'll get the idea (just an example). The code
  * is from my another project.
  */
void MyDump(const void *m, unsigned int n)
{
        const unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(m);
        char buffer[16];
        unsigned int mod = 1;

        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nOffset     | Hex                                                | ASCII            |\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << (long)m << " |";

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++mod) {
                buffer[i % 16] = p[i];

                --mod;

                if (mod % 4 == 0)
                        std::cout << " ";

                ++mod;

                std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(p[i]) << " ";

                if ((mod == 16 && i != 0) || i == n - 1) {
                        if (i == n - 1) {
                                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < (16 - mod) * 3; ++j)
                                        std::cout << " ";

                                if (mod <= 4)
                                        std::cout << " ";

                                if (mod <= 8)
                                        std::cout << " ";

                                if (mod <= 12)
                                        std::cout << " ";
                        }

                        mod = 0;

                        std::cout << "| ";

                        for (unsigned short j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
                                switch (buffer[j]) {
                                        case 0x7:
                                        case 0x8:
                                        case 0x9:
                                        case 0xa:
                                        case 0xb:
                                        case 0xd:
                                        case 0xe:
                                        case 0xf:
                                                std::cout << " ";

                                                break;

                                        default: std::cout << buffer[j];
                                }
                        }

                        std::cout << " |";

                        if (i == n - 1) {
                                std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

                                return;
                        }

                        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

                        std::cout << "\n0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << (long)m + i << " |";
                }
        }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE h_module, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID)
{
        switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
                case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                        /** Do the heap walk here, please see
                          * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee175819%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
                          * for enumerating the heap.
                          */

                        break;

                case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: break;

                case DLL_THREAD_DETACH: break;

                case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        }
}
```

Now that you have the DLL, you still need to inject it to the desired process. This can be easily done with [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/Wikipage) API. Download the library and see an example of unmanaged hook.

Comment: Hmm i think is might work =3 how would i do that inject dll because i never have used one.

Comment: =3 k think this is what im going to try to use tyvm

Answer (score 3):

A program can find addresses of its own variables pretty easily (`&variable`). If it's cooperating in things, it can then send that to the other program by some normal IPC mechanism. The other program won't (normally) be able to do much with it directly though -- at least on a typical system (*BSD, Linux, Windows, etc.) each process will have memory mapped separately, so an address in one isn't directly usable in another.

Nearly all will provide some sort of debugging capability that lets you access one process' memory from another process, but how that works varies widely.

Comment: Why mention IPC as an option but dismiss shared memory as platform-specific? They are equally unportable.

Comment: @Potatocorn:Because some of them aren't really very platform specific. Just for an obvious example, you can spawn the child process with `popen`, and the child writes the address to its standard output. Technically, that's not guaranteed 100% portable, but practically speaking, it's awfully close. Shared memory is much less so. Though it's a guess, I'm also guessing that the intent is something like a debugger and debuggee, where one process has primary responsibility, and the other undergoes only minimal adaptation.

Comment: Or use `mmap` and install a heap inside the shared memory. Although quick and dirty, it at least wouldn't be useless. But I'm not so clear there are two different programs as opposed to successive instances of one program, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After you close and reopen a program, the addresses are all randomized. There's no way to save an address for the next time you run.

Instead, you need to design a file structure for whatever data you have. Write it to a file, expressing structural relationships somehow other than addresses, and restore pointer-links when reading it back. This is called serialization.

Comment: .. =\ i know they are put in a random... spot.
also i can't write it to a file :\

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you understand how the target program working and its internal data structure, you can find the address of the target variable, because each single byte of memory that is dynamically allocated during run time can always be found from some information statically known to code, except variables originated inside a function. However, practically, it's nearly impossible to understand a program by inspecting its binary representation. So you are out of luck:-)

A little more thoughts:

let me guess what you are trying to do: you want to stop an integer counting down in another process. If that the case, you can manually find the address by a game tool, then set a break point by a debugger to pause when the address is written, then make the break point to happen by different possible operations in the target program. This way you could identify which code are decreasing the value and possibly modify the EXE/DLL to disable these code. Chances are the target program will crash more often or does not entertain you any more, for the same code you disabled is used to decrease the energy of you and your opponents:-)

Comment: =\ well i know the program very well but it's data is just placed in the next free area so i don't know how to find it with out searching memory. right now i just find one of the values and i know they are all in order so i can find them all then with a little math but i still have to find one. :(

Comment: By meaning knowing the program very well, I assume you have the source code of the program. In that case, you can modify the source code to put a "marker" data segment before the variable, for example:
struct foo { char marker[8]={'0x23','0xfd',...}; int theVariable;}; then every time you just need to find the marker and you know the actual variable is right after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know the pointer one time to include it in your code, you can use too programs like cheatengine to get the pointer.